# How to install the Zend Framework offline

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have downloaded the file from Git
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/archive/master.zip

and then unzip the file to the working directory.

i have got the error like 'Unable to load ZF2 ...'
i have downloaded the library files and pasted in vendor folder and also created the Envorinmental variable. but still the same issue.

I have come across many such issues in this forum, but no once has said about running/installing Zend OFFLINE.

Can you guys, please give an idea  how to install in both windows and ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Downloading a full copy of Zend Framework 2 separately and extracting it into  `vendor/ZF2/library` should do it. (To see if it worked see if you ended up with a file at `vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php`.)

If not you'll need to debug a little in `init_autoloader.php` to see what's going on.

Doing it 'live' with Composer will make your life easier in the long run though.